# Indexes and time complexity for Oracle CONNECT BY query?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, time-complexity, connect-by

I have multiple hierarchical menus stored in a Oracle 11g table (called `items`), with the following structure:

- `menu`: ID for the menu the item belongs to.
- `id`: ID for the menu item. Unique within the menu, but not within the table.
- `name`: Name of the menu item.
- `parent`: The `id` of the menu items parent (always in the same menu).

The table contains around 100.000 rows. I use the following query to generate a list of all menu items and the their corresponding root item:

```
SELECT
    name,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT name AS root
FROM
    items
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR id = parent AND
    PRIOR menu = menu
START WITH
    parent IS NULL
```

(There might be multiple roots in one menu, so I can not just use an ordinary join without a connect by.)

What indexes do I need to create to optimize this query? I already have a combined index on `id` and `menu` to ensure uniqueness, but do I need any more?

Also, what time complexity will this query have, given that I create the right indexes? Is it related to the total number of items, the number per menu, the depth of the menu?

**EDIT:** This is the output of `EXPLAIN PLAN`:

```
ID | PARENT_ID | OPERATION        | OPTIONS                      | OPTIMIZER
---+-----------+------------------+------------------------------+------------------
0  |           | SELECT STATEMENT |                              | SELECT STATEMENT
1  | 0         | CONNECT BY       | NO FILTERING WITH START-WITH | CONNECT BY
2  | 1         | TABLE ACCESS     | FULL                         | TABLE ACCESS
```

However, this is only on a small dataset of a 100 items, as I do not have the full dataset yet. I have excluded a number of columns for space reasons. Please let me know if you need anything else from the output.

Comment: How many menu items does this table have ? 100 ? 10.000 ? 1.000.000 ?

Comment: @kordirko Around 100.000.

Comment: Well, what does explain plan show?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Must admit that I did not know of `EXPLAIN PLAN`. Looks like a very poverful tool, but I am not sure about how to inerpret the output. I have added some of the output to the question, please let me know if more is needed.

Comment: Looks like you are doing a full table scan, so no indexes are being used.  Please show your index creation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entry point is `parent IS NULL` which will by default never use any index, therefore you get a full table scan. A function based index on this expression might be helpful for large data volumes. The recursion then accesses the table using parent and menu, so a combined index on parent and menu might be reasonable. Having said that execution time should be a function of all the criteria you mentioned, though proper indexing might significantly reduce their impact.